# Rotate the 3d Cursor by 90 degrees relative to view using hotkeys

Tags: shortcut, grease-pencil, 3d-cursor

I want to rotate the 3d Cursor by 90 degrees relative to the view. That way, I can change the position of the Grease Pencil Canvas more easily. If I have to rotate the cursor I have to switch tabs in the N-panel from View to Tool each time I need to rotate the cursor, this kills the flow for me. So I want to rotate the cursor using the arrow keys of my keyboard instead.
Is it possible to create a script to change these values based on my current camera view?
[image]